# Is it conversationally and grammatically correct to say "I usually go jogging in the evening after I finish all my work of the day"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, usage

I am asking because I feel awkward to say "I finish all my work of the day."

I wanted to say it in that way because I am between jobs so I don't really have a routine work. Sometimes I study, sometimes hang out with my fiends, or work part time.

I want to say that I go jogging at the end of the day, whatever I did during the day time. I thougt that if I say "I usually go jogging after work," it would sound like I go to work every weekdays and I go jogging after I come home from work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence would sound completely grammatical and natural if you just say "work for the day" instead of "work of the day."

I wish I could give you good advice about choosing the right preposition here, but I can't see any rhyme or reason for preferring "for" over "of" in this context. It's just what people say.

You are correct that "after work" implies after you get home from your job, while "work for the day" might involve work that is not specifically related to employment, though!

Comment: This was what I wanted to know exactly. I wanted to know how people say the sentence normally, how the sentence would sound natural. Thank you very much! Your advice helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a bit awkward to say "...after I finish all my work of the day."  If you go jogging at the same time every day regardless of what you did earlier day, you could just say "I go jogging every day around five o'clock" or "I go jogging every day in the late afternoon or early evening" or something like that.

If the specific time is dependent on when you finish your other activities and you want to make that clear, you could say something like "I go jogging after I'm done with the rest of my daily activities" or "I go jogging after I finish my tasks for the day" or something like that.

Comment: "I go jogging after I finish my task for the day." will be perfect for me. Thank you very much!